# Getting error from Timestamp format for QGIS Time Manager?

Tags: qgis, format, timemanager

I encounter a strange error in QGIS Timemanager: 
I have two csv-files, encoded UTF-8, EPSG 4326. Only one of them can be read by timemanager-plugin, the other one produces this error-message:

```
An error ocurred while trying to add layer import_points to TimeManager. Cause: '>=' not supported between instances of 'TypeError' and 'int'
```

This is the file that works:

```
timestamp;x;y
03.08.2018;08.53311;47.37276
04.08.2018;71.42991;51.14062
05.08.2018;76.94829;43.25280
06.08.2018;75.25138;42.74670
07.08.2018;72.79717;40.5368
08.08.2018;72.36308;40.78849
09.08.2018;70.93858;40.5349
10.08.2018;69.26461;41.31713
```

With this file, I get the error-message mentioned above:

```
timestamp;x;y
03.08.2018;08.53311;47.37276
04.08.2018;71.42991;51.14062
05.08.2018;76.94829;43.25280
06.08.2018;75.25138;42.74670
07.08.2018;72.79717;40.5368
08.08.2018;72.36308;40.78849
09.08.2018;70.93858;40.5349
10.08.2018;69.26461;41.31713
12.08.2018;66.75750;38.68161
13.08.2018;67.30462;37.24347
15.08.2018;66.97485;39.66931
16.08.2018;66.96718;39.64865
18.08.2018;66.96718;39.64865
```

Why does this second file produces an error?

I can't find any difference in the formatting of the two files, everything seems to be the same, only some more timestamps added.

Comment: @user2656: yes, your'right, my mistake. I made sure to use one of the supported formats, but somehow in the process of adding values (in Excel), it seems the format got changed - so using the format 2018-08-15 19:00 works perfect. If you move your comment to answers, I can accept it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It might be that the plugin is interpreting your timestamp as `%m.%d.%Y` and raises an error when the day (which is being treated as the month) is greater than 12.

Try using one of the timestamp formats listed in the [documentation](https://github.com/anitagraser/TimeManager#what-time-manager-currently-does):

> ```
> Integer timestamp in seconds after or before the epoch (1970-1-1)
> %Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%fZ
> %Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%f
> %Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S
> %Y-%m-%d %H:%M
> %Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S
> %Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%SZ
> %Y-%m-%dT%H:%M
> %Y-%m-%dT%H:%MZ
> %Y-%m-%d
> %Y/%m/%d %H:%M:%S.%f
> %Y/%m/%d %H:%M:%S
> %Y/%m/%d %H:%M
> %Y/%m/%d
> %H:%M:%S
> %H:%M:%S.%f
> %Y.%m.%d %H:%M:%S.%f
> %Y.%m.%d %H:%M:%S
> %Y.%m.%d %H:%M
> %Y.%m.%d
> %Y%m%d%H%M%SED
> ```